# How to select string and output only last text line

Tags: powershell

Anyway I can have my output only search for the last line of each string that I search for?

```
$String1 = "Oatmeal"
$String2 = "Cake"
$String1Location = "C:\1.txt"

try {
    Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $String1, $String2 -ErrorAction Stop 
}

catch {
    return ""
}
```

My output is something like this:

```
C:\1.txt:4:Oatmeal
C:\1.txt:6:Cake
C:\1.txt:9:Cake
C:\1.txt:10:Oatmeal
```

But I only want to see

```
C:\1.txt:9:Cake
C:\1.txt:10:Oatmeal
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do the following in your try block.

```
$found1=Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $String1 -ErrorAction Stop 
$found1[-1]
$found2=Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $String2 -ErrorAction Stop 
$found2[-1]
```

Comment: This the output:
C:\1.txt:4:Oatmeal
C:\1.txt:6:Cake
C:\1.txt:9:Cake
C:\1.txt:10:Oatmeal
C:\1.txt:10:Oatmeal
C:\1.txt:9:Cake

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Did you try the above code in your try block?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with and it is working:

```
try {
    Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $String1 -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_ -match $String1} | Select-Object -Last 1
    Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $String2 -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_ -match $String2} | Select-Object -Last 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
$String1 = "Oatmeal"
$String2 = "Cake"
$String1Location = "C:\1.txt"

Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $string1, $string2 -SimpleMatch | Group-Object Line | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object LineNumber | Select-Object -Last 1
}
```

Or by using a Regex match

```
$StringsToSearch = "Oatmeal","Cake"
$String1Location = "C:\1.txt"

# build the regex
$pattern = '\b(' + (($StringsToSearch | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|') + ')\b' 
# this ends up in '\b(Oatmeal|Cake)\b' which means we are looking for these strings as whole string.
# if you also would like to search for strings that contain the search criteria, like 'Pancake',
# then use 
# $pattern = ($StringsToSearch | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $pattern | Group-Object Line | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object LineNumber | Select-Object -Last 1
}
```

<sup>Note: If you want your output to be sorted on the Line number in ascending order, simply add `| Sort-Object LineNumber` after the last closing curly bracket.</sup>

Comment: Here the line **IS** the pattern, in case the pattern is only part of the line your approach won't work. So better group by the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is IMO to append `| Sort-Object Pattern -Unique`
and if neccessary to `| Sort-Object LineNumber` to have the original order.

```
$String1 = "Oatmeal"
$String2 = "Cake"
$String1Location = "C:\1.txt"

try {
    Select-String -Path $String1Location -Pattern $String1, $String2 -ErrorAction Stop |
       Sort-Object Pattern -Unique | Sort-Object LineNumber
}

catch {
    return ""
}
```